# Python pymysql: How to load an image from database?

Tags: python, mysql, blob, pyqt5, qimage

I want to load and display an image from my database within a PyQt5 window.
But my script doesn't work.

```
    connection = None
    result = None

    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                                     user = 'root',
                                     db = 'mydatabase',
                                     cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "SELECT image FROM mydatabase"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                result = cursor.fetchall() #Get all values from the image column

                image = QImage()
                image.load(result[0]['Image']) #Load image from the first row

                label = QLabel()
                label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
                self.grid.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

What should I do to display the image?

Comment: Does it show any error. Have you looked at the logs. You can enable the logs of the library if necessary.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show any errors. The log only gave me a strange looking code like "b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\xef\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xc8..." and so on. It represents the LONGBLOB image from the database.

Comment: And I also want the image to be saved as "imagename.png".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` method only takes a file-path or an `IODevice`, whereas you seem to be passing in the raw image data as bytes.

Try this, instead:

```
image = QImage.fromData(result[0]['Image'])
```

To save the image, do this:

```
image.save('image.png')
```

Comment: Now I receive "libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile".